# (c#) How to check if a certain exe is located on a users computer?

Tags: c#

i'm wondering how i would test and see if a certain exe is located on a users computer? For example if i wanted to find skype i would run a function like this:

```
if(checkForSkypeonUsrcomputer("Skype.exe")==true){
    //Script detects skype.exe on users computer 
} else {
    //Script detects skype.exe is not on users computer 
}

checkForSkypeonUsrcomputer(string exetype)
{
    CheckForExeOnUsersComputer(exetype);
    return TrueOrFalse;
}
```

^    Thats just a example trying to explain what im trying to do    ^

I've looked everywhere for a solution and couldn't find one.

Comment: Try this page "How to iterate through directorys"
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx

Comment: If such a function existed, what would you *do* once you had that answer? Rather than taking a piecemeal approach here, give us the big picture about what goal you're trying to achieve. There may be a solution that doesn't start with "find the exe on the use's computer".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find the app in the registry under the "Uninstall" key. 
**HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall**
All apps that can be uninstalled are listed here, and you can find them by their display name as such:

```
private string FindByDisplayName(RegistryKey parentKey, string name)
         {
             string[] nameList = parentKey.GetSubKeyNames();
             for (int i = 0; i < nameList.Length; i++)
             {
                 RegistryKey regKey =  parentKey.OpenSubKey(nameList[i]);
                 try
                 {
                     if (regKey.GetValue("DisplayName").ToString() == name)
                     {
                         return regKey.GetValue("InstallLocation").ToString();
                     }
                 }
                 catch { }
             }
             return "";
         }
```

Let me know if this works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

[try this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles(v=vs.110).aspx)
you can filter results on basis of extension and even you can filter on basis of filename(s) too
.

Directory.GetFiles(dirpath).Where(file => file.EndsWith(".ext"))